# Temporarily "maximize" one window and later return to previous window layout

Tags: vim

With multiple windows open, is there a way to temporarily close all windows except for the active one and later reopen all the windows as they were?

I know that `only` will close all other windows except for the active one but I don't know how to then go back to the previous window layout. `mksession` almost does this. Is there a good way to glue these together?

Comment: Pro-tip: `<c-w>o`/`<c-w><c-o>` is the same as `:only` (See `:h :only`). Making it even better by turn off diff-ing at the same time: `nnoremap <silent> <c-w>o :diffoff!<bar>only<cr>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's probably a plugin for that but you can simply open the current buffer in a new tab page:

```
:tabe[dit] %
```

Comment: [ZoomWin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=508) would be one such plugin, but I personally think this solution is way better

Comment: I did find ZoomWin after asking the question and I tried it but this is better. ZoomWin is quite slow to return to the window layout.